# Linking with code that does not support exception handling (C++/LLVM)

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to use llvm as a code-generation back-end to my software and just realized that llvm was compiled without support for C++ exception handling (for efficiency). In my software, however, I use exception handling extensively.

If I wrap all my callback functions in try-catch-blocks (so that no exceptions need to be propagated "through" the llvm code), can I then safely remove the "-fno-exceptions" (for GCC) from my linker flags? (this flag is normally required when linking with llvm, as it turns up when doing `llvm-config --cxxflags`).

If not, does the situation change if I wrap the llvm functions with functions declared with "throws ()"? The implementation of these functions could be compiled with -fno-exceptions.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on ABI compability, but who knows? It may be easier and safer to compile LLVM yourself with exceptions enabled.

Comment: @delnan Compiling llvm is not an option. My software is used by several people on different platforms (linux, mac, windows) and I need to rely on the default llvm installation that you get e.g. from apt-get.

Comment: @delnan: I don't know much about ABI compatibility, but would I get it in this case if functions are declared with throws()? I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: AFAIK, LLVM packages in most Linux distros are built with exceptions and RTTI.

Comment: @arrowdodger On Ubuntu 10.4 at least, it was not the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I wrap all my callback functions in try-catch-blocks (so that no exceptions need to be propagated "through" the llvm code), can I then safely remove the "-fno-exceptions" (for GCC) from my linker flags?

Yes, assuming you have a suitable way of reporting whatever conditions caused the exceptions to be thrown.

`-fexceptions` is the default for C++. `-fno-exceptions` is the default for C. There is no problem at all mixing C++ code compiled with the default options together with C code compiled with the default options, so there cannot be a problem mixing `-fexceptions` with `-fno-exceptions`.

But consider adding `-fexceptions` instead of removing `-fno-exceptions`: parsing command-line options in the exact same way as GCC is complicated, and there is no need for you to attempt to do so.

Comment: OK! That's all I need to know. Didn't think about the parallel to C. Thanks!